# UWP GetFilesAsync

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to get all the "*.csv" files in the LocalState folder.  and get the following error.

System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
        StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFolder assets = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("*.csv");
        var files = await assets.GetFilesAsync();
```

Comment: `*.csv` is not a valid folder name.

Comment: Also, `.LocalFolder` is not your installation folder but your local data folder below that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using File Queries :

```
//this may be any folder you want.
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var options = new QueryOptions();
options.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");//this will add .csv files to query options 
options.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;//optional
StorageFileQueryResult query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

[MSDN - StorageFileQueryResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.storagefilequeryresult)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The following code found the files with *.csv properties.

```
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> x = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        int tempCt = x.Count;
        foreach (StorageFile file in x)
        {

            if (file.Name.ToString().Contains("csv"))
            {
                sb.Append(file.Name + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

May not be the best , but it works.